# Convert long series keys to hex, then Choose desired values from a list of long separated keys

Tags: python, hex

I have code to generate series of keys as in below:

```
def Keygen (x,r,size):
 key=[]
 for i in range(size):
    x= r*x*(1-x) 
    key.append(int((x*pow(10,16))%256))
 return key   
if __name__=="__main__":
    key=Keygen(0.45,0.685,92)#Intial Parameters 
    print('nx key:', key, "\n")
```

The output keys are:

```
nx key: [0, 11, 53, 42, 111, 38, 55, 102, 252, 155, 54, 219, 149, 220, 235, 177, 140, 46, 209, 249, 46, 241, 218, 243, 6, 166, 247, 106, 33, 24, 220, 185, 129, 182, 214, 210, 180, 28, 84, 117, 228, 213, 205, 240, 125, 37, 181, 234, 246, 54, 22, 195, 38, 174, 212, 166, 9, 237, 25, 225, 81, 23, 244, 235, 171, 196, 111, 182, 227, 26, 22, 246, 35, 52, 225, 249, 90, 237, 162, 111, 76, 52, 35, 24, 16, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

I try to convert all key values to hex by used the following code:

```
K=hex(key)
print('nx key:', key, "\n")
```

But when run I got the error "TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Then try to use "K= hex(ord(key))" but also got another error "TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but list found"

What I need is to convert all keys to hex, then select just 4 keys to be like this

```
K = (0x3412, 0x7856, 0xBC9A, 0xF0DE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get hex values for your list of keys, you have to iterate over the list and turn each element seperately into a hex value:

```
K = tuple(hex(x) for x in key)
```

Then you can select 4 random keys (no repeat) from this list by:

```
import random
selectedKeys = random.sample(K, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you, the code is converted.. But for section 2 I need to select it not randomly I need to select from desired location in this series.. To explain if  the result nx key: [k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8, k9] i need a =(k2,k4,k5,k9)

Comment: You can just select the elements you want by another list generator: [K[x] for x in select] where select =  [2,4,5,9]

Comment: Thank you for support and great help. My final question after making hex by code you mentioned the output is between single quotes like this key= ('0x0', '0xb', '0x35', '0x2a', '0x6f', '0x26') how to make it without single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better name for key is **keys**, cause is a list of keys. That said

`[hex(key) for key in keys]`

should do the trick.

This a is a usage of [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output with your values wrapped in [], you have a list for key. What you then want to do is iterate through each element in that list to apply your hex.

```
hexed_keys = [hex(i) for i in key]
```

Comment: Thank you, the code is converted.. But for section 2 I need to select it not randomly I need to select from desired location in this series.. To explain if the result nx key: [k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8, k9] i need a =(k2,k4,k5,k9)